# calculating difference in quantiles

Tags: python

```
R  Year     Time    POE VALUE
1   2020    0:00    10% 0
1   2020    0:00    25% 0
1   2020    0:00    50% 0
1   2020    0:00    75% 0
1   2020    0:00    95% 0
1   2020    0:05    10% 0
1   2020    0:05    25% 0
1   2020    0:05    50% 0
1   2020    0:05    75% 0
1   2020    0:05    95% 0
```

I have this dataset and I wish to want to calculate the difference in quantiles in these to understand how the POE on a graph. Can someone help me with the code?

Comment: The dataset represents POEs (calculated using quantile function in python) for a different time intervals. for eg. - the 10% value at 0.00 time is 0. I want to calculate difference between 25% to 10% using python. Does that help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.